# Disabling global type definitions from library on JS project

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm refactoring a legacy JS project using VS Code and the "checkJs" TypeScript flag.

```json
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true
  }
}
```

After I have moved some files, there are some variables named `Event` which should be flagged as non defined, but aren't. If I Shift+click one of them, I get pointed to a global `Event` variable declared in `@types/react/global.d.ts`.

How do I stop TS from adding React and DOM's global type definitions (like `Event`) to my scope? In a JavaScript project.

Comment: It's a global in web and Node; why don't you want it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/exclude.html) property to exclude certain typing files:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "exclude": ["node_modules/@types/react/global.d.ts"]
  }
}
```

Comment: These types are not coming from node_modules, but from a global TS cache (remember this is a JS project and types are auto acquired). I don't think this is gonna work.

Comment: > And types are auto acquired
What do you mean by this?